# Sort byte array using Array.sort()

Tags: java

Really stupid question, but I'm a bit stuck on this one:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[]{1, 2, 3};
Arrays.sort(bytes, (byte a, byte b) -> 0);
```

Why isn't the lambda matching any methods of `Array.sort` and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no `sort` methods accepting an array of primitive values **and** a `Comparator`. Only arrays of objects can be sorted with a comparator unfortunately.

Try

```
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
Arrays.sort(bytes, (Byte a, Byte b) -> 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess you're trying to use [`Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)), so the problem is that `byte` isn't a `T`, because it's a primitive type. I guess this would work with `Byte` instead.